# Execute two client listeners one after another

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, oracle-adf

Imagine that we have a button. When someone clicks on it an action listener is executed then followed by `<af:clientListener method="method1" type="action"/>` action. During the execution of the action listener the logic changes and I want `<af:clientListener method="method2" type="...."/>` to be executed. Is is possible to stop the execution of the first client listener and to start execution of the second listener?

```
 <af:commandButton text="Click me" id="btn" actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.someBean.action}">
         <af:clientListener method="method1" type="action"/>
         <af:clientListener method="method2" type="...."/>
 </af:commandButton>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you have one clientListener with methodX and then call method1, method2 or both from inside it based on a given condition.

Comment: @amishra is right (as can be seen in several 'duplicates' in stackoverflow